# Compare documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider following collection named sales:

```
[
  {
    product: "Banana",
    timestamp: 1672992000,
    price: 5,
  },
  {
    product: "Banana",
    timestamp: 1672992001,
    price: 6,
  },
  {
    product: "Pineapple",
    timestamp: 1672992000,
    price: 9,
  },
  {
    product: "Pineapple",
    timestamp: 1672992001,
    price: 8,
  },
  {
    product: "Melon",
    timestamp: 1672992005,
    price: 15,
  },
  
]
```

How do we query product sales that have higher consecutive prices?

In our example it would be banana with price of 6.

- not melon, as we don't have anything to compare to
- not pineapple, as the later sale has lower price, than the previous one

Obviously there could be more than 2 sales per product.

Is it possible to do with aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$product",    //for each product,
      "sortBy": {timestamp: 1},     //sort by timestamp
      "output": {
        "lPrice": {
          $max: "$price",           //add a field whose value is price value of next document
          "window": {
            "documents": [1,1]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },                               //output of this stage has current price and next price
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: ["$lPrice", "$price"] //filter the documents where next price is higher than current price
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1oLuoXKFyAS)

Comment: That's amazing! Worked like a charm. Didn't even know about `$setWindowFields`, thanks!